# How to post on Facebook user's wall every time the user uses the Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to publish to a Facebook User's wall when user uses the App from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003779/how-to-publish-to-a-facebook-users-wall-when-user-uses-the-app-from-my-website)

I developed a Facebook application using PHP from my website. I would like that every time such user uses the application - a post is posted on his/her wall stating that they are using the application and a link to my website.

Can this be done? If yes, how?

Comment: Please don't do this. :(

Comment: Why not please? Can you explain, please? :-)

Comment: I think @Amber doesnt want you to do this because it might annoy the user? That is just speculation on my part, but I would find it annoying :P

Comment: @Bono I would like to do it basically because I have a commerce website, and I would like to let sellers on my website advertise their products. Therefore, in the meantime I would like customers on their facebook profile to be notified that the seller has posted on my wall :-)

Comment: Would I want that kind of advertising on my wall, every time a new product get’s published to your store, maybe even for my friends or everyone to see it? I guess not. Maybe app-to-user notifications would better suit your use case. Anyway, if you want to post it to your user’s wall, you should get their explicit consent first, I’d say (not necessarily by platform policies, but by common decency), and also give them the possibility to opt-out at any time. Otherwise, you’ll only hurt yourself anyway,

Comment: [continued] because more and more users blocking your posts will decrease your apps general visibility on the platform. As for your question if it _can_ be done – sure, if you get the required permission (publish_stream). If your not familiar with the API, please have a look in Facebooks developer section to see how it works.

Comment: You'll be shut down within a week if you start that

Comment: The recommended thing to do is to have a pop-up that the user then clicks, or cancels. It's not auto-posted. Using open graph, you get the user's permission to post on their behalf, and then post to the activity stream when they use it. Both are OK by Facebook (and generally, user, standards.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to do this then you *should* use the Dialog API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

If you do this automatically, users may report your app which may cause Facebook to take it down. It's much better to use a dialog as you're **prompting** the user to post a message rather than doing it for them.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for Open Graph functionality, that wraps up usage to and allows you to post custom stories like "Anna listend to Spotify." Note, you have to have extra permissions to post without a dialog, called "publish_stream."

As for posting on each usage, get the jQuery's document.ready() method and put your Javascript dialog publish bit in there.

This isn't recommended- it's quite annoying. Usually, you have the user post according to some action, or activity, that they want to share. Not just usage. By the way you asked your question, that's why I mentioned Open Graph. That's more accepted now.

(updated) to do via PHP, get the access token, which means forming the authentication url. Have the user "login", which will send them to Facebook to authenticate. When they revisit yoru site, they'll have a "code" which you exchange for an access token (documented on Facebook site). So, you'd have to keep track that the user is in their initial visit, with some kind of session state variable. When they come back after authentication, store their access token, and check to see if they're still on their first visit, then, display a form for posting to their wall. When they've filled out the form, use form submit to Facebook the publish information for the feed post.

This is also not recommended- even the examples on Facebook's site use a hybrid of PHP and Javascript to create the same functionality.

The best thing to do: use Javascript SDK, and use Open Graph.

Comment: How can I do this using PHP please?

Comment: I want to do this ideally using PHP

Comment: It's complicated- and even Facebook recommends doing this via Javascript SDK.

Comment: Thanks Anna. How can I do it via JavaScript

Comment: See the example "platform dialogs" and setting up the JS/SDK <http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/>