# How to publish to a Facebook User's wall when user uses the App from my website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook Application using PHP that allows user to upload photos to my facebook page.

Now I want that whenever the user posts on my wall via this Facebook application - the user is prompted to publish a message on his/her wall such as 'John has posted a picture of Evil Monkey's Wall'. Always let the User prompt whether to accept this or not.

Can this be done and integrated into my existing Facebook Application please? Can you please provide me with some sample code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Output that code to the screen from the PHP code.  I presume there's a way for PHP too write to the HTTP Response.